# Understanding opamp circuit, 13 MHz (interference?) amplification

Tags: operational-amplifier, differential, interference, cutoff-frequency

I have the circuit drawn below soldered to a prototyping board.

[image]

First, I added a high-pass filter a with cutoff-frequency of 600 kHz, since I would like to receive around 2 MHz.

Then the received signal is to be amplified with the opa2863DR.
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa2863.pdf

The maximal amplification could be 25x since the GBW of the opa2863 equals 50 MHz, if I'm understanding correctly, when applying a 2 MHz signal. But, since R3 is only to 200k, the maximal amplification would be 21x, which is feasible for the opa2863 for the prior reasoning.

After the amplifier I added another filter, a high-pass filter with a cutoff-frequency of around 7.2 MHz.

I power the circuit (5V) using a ROCKSEED RS305P and the input signal is delivered on a SIGLENT SDG 2082X (2 MHz sinewave, 1 Vpp).

I noticed that, when not applying an input signal, my circuit attenuates a frequency of 13.9 MHz (around that number with 0.1 MHz fluctuations).

I would not be so sure how this could happen. Is something in my setup chosen incorrectly such that the circuit delivers a 13.9 MHz signal for some reason? When I change R3 the strength changes. I added R4 and C2 to get rid of the 13.9 MHz signal, which is not working. Should I have added it in front of R2?

The issue with this interference is that the signal received on Vin +/- is very weak so I need to amplify it quite a bit. The interference of 13.9 MHz just takes over when doing that.

Do the values that I chose make sense, and if not, could someone explain to me what my misconceptions could be?

Photo of the oscilloscope readings that show the interference / oscillations:
[image]

Comment: "my circuit attenuates a frequency of 13.9 MHz " - Do you mean it oscillates?

Comment: How's your decoupling situation?

Comment: You should wire to ground unused pins 5 and 6.

Comment: You need to bias the op-amp so the output is above ground at DC, for starters.

Comment: @JRE I am not quite sure, I think so? For clarification I did add a photo that I just toke from the oscilloscope (Vout) readings. 
-----
winny could you elaborate that question? I used the balun to decouple but I am not sure if that is what you mean. 
-----
Antonio51 I can do/try that. Could you explain the reasoning behind that? All in all, I'm trying to learn why stuff works :)
-----
SpehroPefhany thanks for the suggestion! How would I achieve that, and also why? what would it accomplish?

Comment: Decoupling capacitors for the voltage rails feeding your opamp.

Comment: ah, tbh, no I do not have those, I did forget them since I was not thinking of a final prototype. Will try to add those!

Comment: "Attenuate" means to reduce an existing signal by some amount.  Since you are not giving your circuit a 13MHz signal, it cannot be attenuating it.

Comment: Fair @JRE. The reason that I do use "attenuate" (which might be better of called "amplify") is that the strength of the 13 MHz signal changes when I change the opamp gain using R3.

Comment: Fix the dc offset problem as Spehro mentioned. It's no good doing anything else until this is fixed. Your output quiescent voltage should be about mid-rail. At the moment it will be hard against the 0 volt rail and that is wrong.

Comment: @Andyaka and SephroPefhany, that is something I did not know. So I could achieve this by connecting pin 3 of my opamp to the output of a voltage divider, bypassed with a capacitor?

Comment: Connect pin 3 instead of to 0 volts, to 2.5 volts. Make only that change. You can use lowish value resistors but they will need a bypass capacitor to ensure that the "manufactured" 2.5 volts has very low AC impedance. Use 10 nF capacitors for this.

Comment: Yes, what I thought. Last question, why specifically 10 nF and not 100 or 1u e.g.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *could someone explain to me what my misconceptions could be?*

You need to bias your input like this: -

[image]

You can use a 1 kΩ potential divider splitting the 5 volts and 0 volts but, add a 10 nF capacitor from the centre-node to 0 volts. 10 nF is good in terms of high-frequency performance compared to some 100 nF (or larger) capacitors.

Comment: In addition, I moved c2 and R4 to the left, In series with R1 and C1 to have the filtering prior to amplifying. With your suggestion, now the setup works best! Thank you!